# Adding Events to MenuItem Dyanamically in C#

Tags: c#

I have created menu dynamically.But I don't know how to handle events of menu Item.Please Let me know if anyone have solution.Thanks in Advance.

```
ToolStripMenuItem master,transaction,report,exit;
        private void Menu1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            master = new ToolStripMenuItem("Master");
            menuStrip1.Items.Add(master);

            master.DropDownItems.Add("Party Master");
            master.DropDownItems.Add("Item Master");
            master.DropDownItems.Add("Tax Master");
            master.Click += MenuClicked;

            transaction = new ToolStripMenuItem("Transaction");
            menuStrip1.Items.Add(transaction);
            transaction.DropDownItems.Add("Inward");
            transaction.DropDownItems.Add("Inoice");
            transaction.DropDownItems.Add("Daily Expense");

            report = new ToolStripMenuItem("Report");
            menuStrip1.Items.Add(report);
            report.DropDownItems.Add("Master Report");
            report.DropDownItems.Add("Transaction Report");
            report.DropDownItems.Add("Daily Expense Report");

            exit = new ToolStripMenuItem("Exit");
            menuStrip1.Items.Add(exit);
        }

        private void MenuClicked(object o,EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((((ToolStripMenuItem)o).Text) == "Party Master")
            {
                Master.PartyMaster p = new Master.PartyMaster();
                p.Show();
            }
        }`
```

Comment: does the handler not fire when menu clicked?

Comment: Yes.Its not working

Comment: Do you have a compelling reason to create this menu **dynamically**?  Why not create it in the designer and wire up the events that way?  It doesn't look like you have any logic that changes what will be in the menu at run-time...it looks static.

Answer (score 0):

Try add your dropdown items this way:

```
        ToolStripItem partyMaster = new ToolStripMenuItem() { Text = "Party Master" };
        partyMaster.Click += MenuClicked;
        ToolStripItem itemMaster = new ToolStripMenuItem() { Text = "Item Master" };
        itemMaster.Click += MenuClicked;
        ToolStripItem taxMaster = new ToolStripMenuItem() { Text = "Tax Master" };
        taxMaster.Click += MenuClicked;

        master.DropDownItems.Add(partyMaster);
        master.DropDownItems.Add(itemMaster);
        master.DropDownItems.Add(taxMaster);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        `// Master 
        master.DropDownItems.
            AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] 
            {
                partyMaster,
                itemMaster,
                taxMaster
            }
            );
        master.Name = "Master";
        master.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 20);
        master.Text = "Master";
        master.Click += new System.EventHandler(master_Click);

        // Party Master
        partyMaster.Name = "PartyMaster";
        partyMaster.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(152, 22);
        partyMaster.Text = "PartyMaster";
        partyMaster.Click += new System.EventHandler(partyMaster_Click);

        // Item Master
        itemMaster.Name = "ItemMaster";
        itemMaster.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(152, 22);
        itemMaster.Text = "ItemMaster";

        // Tax Master
        taxMaster.Name = "TaxMaster";
        taxMaster.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(152, 22);
        taxMaster.Text = "TaxMaster"; //`
```

Or more dynamically with List and for loop.

`List<ToolStripMenuItem> items = new List<ToolStripMenuItems>();`

And loop to add more items to the Menu

`ToolStripMenuItem item = new ToolStripMenuItem();`

`items.Add(item);`

`item.Click += new EventHandler(MenuClicked); // if you want to stick with only one function`